# How can I program a JS button who activate a transition on click and on scroll too?

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have a .js document who allow me to switch between different page into the same html document.
I have a trigger button who activate the transition on click only and i wanted to activate it on scroll too or on scroll only.
I tried to add an onscroll parameter in my function but it doesn't worked. I think it's because I have my different pages who are in width:100% so I don't have any scrollbar...

Here is my HTML structure

```
<body>
    <button id="iterateEffects" class="btn_bot"></button>    <!--Trigger btn-->

    <div id="pt-main" class="pt-perspective">
        <div class="pt-page pt-page-1">First page code inside</div>
        <div class="pt-page pt-page-2">Second page code inside</div>
        etc...
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is my button function

```
$iterate = $( '#iterateEffects' ) //my iterateEffects var

function init() {

    $pages.each( function() {
        var $page = $( this );
        $page.data( 'originalClassList', $page.attr( 'class' ) );
    } );

    $pages.eq( current ).addClass( 'pt-page-current' );

    $( '#dl-menu' ).dlmenu( {
        animationClasses : { in : 'dl-animate-in-2', out : 'dl-animate-out-2' },
        onLinkClick : function( el, ev ) {
            ev.preventDefault();
            nextPage( el.data( 'animation' ) );
        }
    } );

    $iterate.on( 'click', function() {
        animcursor = 3;
        nextPage( animcursor );
    } );  //Activate the function on click

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
   $( document ).on( 'scroll', function() {
        animcursor = 3;
        nextPage( animcursor );
    } );
```

Also make sure that your page *is* scrollable.

Comment: Hi Moin, thank you for your answer.
It works but I have one issue. I can change to page 2 when I scroll down but I have to alternate between scroll top/scroll down to switch pages. Is there any solution to enable only scroll down without this problem ?
EDIT : I changed page height from 100% to 101% to get my page scrollable but this is why i have to switch between scroll top/scroll down. Is there a solution to enable scroll without the display of the scroll bar ?

Comment: @BaptisteVandel I don't know any viable option to suppress scrollbar and still have the scroll. Although you can restrict it to work on either up or down scroll.

Comment: I think I found a solution with jquery mousewheel plugin available here https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel. Thank you for your help.